# Can Cauchy theorem be applied to $\log{(z)}e^{ixz}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, contour-integration, analyticity

I'm reading about asymptotic analysis on the integral $I(x)=\int_0^1{\ln{t}e^{ixt}}dt$. The book tells me that I can use Cauchy theorem to deform the contour into a rectangular contour: $0 \to iT \to 1+iT \to 1 \to 0$ (where $T$ is any finite number).

[image: contour]

My question is:

Isn't $\ln{t}e^{ixt}$ singular at $t=0$? Why can I apply Cauchy theorem then?

Do I add a quarter circle around the origin to avoid the singularity? I don't think it works because if you let $z=re^{i\theta}$, then $\lim_{r\to 0}{\int_0^{\pi /2}{\ln{(z)}e^{ixz}}d\theta}\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**We could show what you want using the estimation lemma.**

Let $C_r$ be the quarter circle of radius $r$ that you're interested in.  Then, since $$|\log(z)| = \sqrt{(\log |z|)^2 + (\arg z)^2},$$ we have

$$
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{C_r} \log(z) e^{ixz}\,dz\right| &\leq \frac{\pi}{2} r \cdot \max_{z \in C_r} \left|\log(z) e^{ixz}\right| \\
&\leq \frac{\pi}{2} r \sqrt{(\log r)^2 + (\pi/2)^2} \cdot \max_{z \in C_r} \left|e^{ixz}\right| \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} r \sqrt{(\log r)^2 + (\pi/2)^2} \cdot \max_{\theta \in [0,\pi/2]} e^{-xr \sin \theta} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} r \sqrt{(\log r)^2 + (\pi/2)^2} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} r |\log r| \sqrt{1 + \pi^2/(2 \log r)^2}
\end{align}
$$

for $0 < r < 1$.  Then, since $r \log r \to 0$ as $r \to 0^+$, the result follows.

**Alternately, we could show it by parameterizing the contour.**

Letting $z = r e^{i\theta}$ yields

$$
\int_{C_r} \log(z) e^{ixz}\,dz = i r \int_0^{\pi/2} \log(r e^{i \theta}) e^{i x r e^{i\theta}} e^{i \theta}\,d\theta.
$$

Now

$$
\log(r e^{i\theta}) = \log r + i\theta,
$$

so we can rewrite this as

$$
i r \log r \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{i x r e^{i\theta}} e^{i\theta}\,d\theta - r \int_0^{\pi/2} \theta e^{i x r e^{i\theta}} e^{i\theta}\,d\theta.
$$

Since

$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{i x r e^{i\theta}} e^{i\theta}\,d\theta \longrightarrow \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{i\theta}\,d\theta = 1+i,
$$

$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \theta e^{i x r e^{i\theta}} e^{i\theta}\,d\theta \longrightarrow \int_0^{\pi/2} \theta e^{i\theta}\,d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} - 1 + i,
$$

and

$$
r\log r \longrightarrow 0
$$

as $r \to 0^+$, we see that

$$
\int_{C_r} \log(z) e^{ixz}\,dz \longrightarrow 0
$$

as $r \to 0^+$.

Comment: I'm not sure about you **estimation lemma** approach. The first formula doesn't seem to be correct. It should be $|\log{(z)}|^2 =(\log{|z|})^2 +|\arg{z}|^2$ which will make the following argument fail.

Comment: @user33869 thanks for spotting the typo.  The argument still holds though, and I've added a hint for how to see it.

Comment: Now, it's perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user33869 You're very welcome.